# JQuery toggling all divs in an .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my posts lopping on an .each loop and I have a link to display comments on the bottom of the loop.

I want to show the comment section on click, but when I click comments for all posts open as well. I only want the one that's clicked to open.

I've tried a ton of different examples I've found on this site, but so far none of them have worked.

I'm sure this is extremely easy to accomplish, but I'm a JavaScript noob.

Here is the JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/omgwhyamisobad/h0yhvqa3/

As well as the code snippet -

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.artist-micropost-comment-click').click(function() {
    $('.artist-micropost-comments-container').toggle();
  });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="artist-micropost-social">
  <a class="artist-micropost-comment-click">comments</a>
</div>
<div class="artist-micropost-comments-container">
...
...
...
</div>

<div class="artist-micropost-social">
  <a class="artist-micropost-comment-click">comments</a>
</div>
<div class="artist-micropost-comments-container">
...
...
...
</div>

<div class="artist-micropost-social">
  <a class="artist-micropost-comment-click">comments</a>
</div>
<div class="artist-micropost-comments-container">
...
...
...
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.artist-micropost-comments-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that you are trying to grab the relevant element is wrong. You need to traverse the DOM with respect to the element that is being clicked. If you try to use the direct class selector in this case, then it would select all the elements which are having the supplied class.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.artist-micropost-comment-click').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.artist-micropost-social')
             .next('.artist-micropost-comments-container').toggle();
  });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h0yhvqa3/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.artist-micropost-comment-click').click(function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('.artist-micropost-social') //Find parent container
            .next('.artist-micropost-comments-container') //Find next comments container
            .toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This [**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h0yhvqa3/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.artist-micropost-comment-click').click(function() {
      $( this ).parent().next().slideDown().siblings('.artist-micropost-comments-container').slideUp();

  });
});
```